# Esconder parte do link ao passar o mouse

Tags: php, html

Bom eu tenho um sistema de afiliados do Adfly "Easy Link" conforme mostro no print abaixo.. o sistema que eles usam devo inserir o link do afiliado antes da url que eu queira usar a propaganda conforme mostra abaixo, o que eu gostaria de fazer é esconder essa url deles de forma que ao passar o mouse não mostre apenas isso... se alguém puder ajudar agradeço. Estou com receio que isso possa impactar no resultado de busca do meu site... exemplo o google pode entender o link completo juntando com o Adfly

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer.... No seu site, você quer que esse link encurtado não apareça para o usuário?

Comment: Não tem link encurtado.. esse método é apenas para vc passar primeiro pelos anúncios e depois vai para o meu site... quero camuflar o link deles e mostrar apenas o meu site.

Comment: Não dá para fazer isso, seria uma quebra de segurança do browser, não acha? Isso seria uma maravilha, no site tem um link para A mas na verdade o link vai para B que está infestado de scripts maliciosos. O que você pode fazer é colocar o link para seu site, para uma página específica que redireciona para o adf.ly, que por sua vez irá redirecionar para o seu site novamente. Mas na minha opinião, se abrir um blog que me redireciona para outra página com propaganda, fecho na hora e procuro outro.

Comment: @FilipeMoraes isso depende do Nicho que vc esta acessando.. garanto que muitos não pensam assim tanto que estou tendo um resultado positivo.. DanielOmine seu fresco no outro quero unificar nesse quero esconder.. fica ai de boa.